# 100mbps over Gbit link

Tags: networking

I have a windows 10 machine. Intel 819-v Ethernet card locked at 1Gbit. Also would auto negotiate 1 Gbit. 
Problem: I get only 100mbps thruput.

Other computers connected to switch in another room with uplink to same switch as the one above all runs gbit. All does 300/300 Mbit as I pay for when using Speedtest. Windows 10/Mac/Linux/iPhone over wireless.

But this one windows machine has problems. Any ideas what to fix ? Did update drivers. Tried 2 ports in switch

Comment: Have you tried bypassing the switch (i.e. connecting the machine directly to the switch's uplink cable), or using a different switch?

Comment: Did you check the cable? Gigabit requires 4 pairs, 100megabit can work on 2!

Comment: Boot to a live Linux system to ensure that it is not a driver/software config issue.

Comment: Strange things. Laptop claimed 1Gbps as well. Limited to 100Mbps testing. Rebooted SE2500. Then 1Gbps. 
But office computers were down to 100mbps. Seemed like only one port wanting to run 1Gbps + of course the uplink.

Comment: Tried the Asus AC750 AP as switch. Did not bring up link. Still forces 1Gbps at PC end. Took my Ethernet tool and squeezed both ends again. And now I seem to have it working. 

Still wonder why issue moved from one port/cable to the other and why it finally works. Maybe cable was marginal ? But should not give issue to other cable in switch.